# Proper way to authenticate to Web API from SPA MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

So, I'm not super strong on the intricancies of the new OWIN framework and have the following issue:

I have a SPA web application (latest MVC, AngularJs), latest OWIN, Identity framework is connected to RavenDB user store (using Brock's provider)..

Need: Login user thru username/password or thru Twitter/Fb/LiveId on the SPA website and have that action authenticate future Web API calls made from the browser in a secure fashion. During authentication, I need to pass a number of claims to Web API so that it knows not only who the user is, but also his/her permissions.
Furthermore, need to have Web API be called as an API with use of API Keys (this part I think I got).

What's the proper way to do this?  I'm also planning to have mobile apps connect to the Web API in the future too.  Been reading numerous articles and my head is spinning already.

Issue:  I thought using cookie authentication mode would do it for me.  I've got the setup working for Visual Studio debugging mode and thought I was good.  However, when I deployed into Azure, I've started getting 401 Unauthorized from API calls. Both the SPA website and API are running under the same root domain but different subdomains. I'm not using any cookie domain setting when testing locally from Visual Studio. I'm using root domain for cookies when in Azure.

Here's my SPA's MVC application ConfigAuth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var decryptor = new SettingsEncryption();

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
        CookieDomain = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AuthCookieDomain"),
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        //CookiePath = "/",
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
    });

    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        clientId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LiveIdOAuthAppId")),
        clientSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LiveIdOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
       consumerKey: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("TwitterOAuthAppId")),
       consumerSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("TwitterOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
       appId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FacebookOAuthAppId")),
       appSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FacebookOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
        clientId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("GoogleOAuthAppId")),
        clientSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("GoogleOAuthSecretKey")));
}
```

Here's my Web API ConfigAuth:

```
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieDomain = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AuthCookieDomain"),
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        //CookiePath = "/",
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
        },

    });

    //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        clientId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LiveIdOAuthAppId")),
        clientSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LiveIdOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        consumerKey: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("TwitterOAuthAppId")),
        consumerSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("TwitterOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        appId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FacebookOAuthAppId")),
        appSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FacebookOAuthSecretKey")));

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
        clientId: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("GoogleOAuthAppId")),
        clientSecret: decryptor.Decrypt(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("GoogleOAuthSecretKey")));

    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Furthermore, a global handler has been enabled on the Web API to auth every call.  (inherits from DelegatingHandler, checks Headers for API Key if it exists or calls AssertAuth() otherwise)

Comment: Have you set same machine key in both web site?

Answer (score 1):

Well I've composed a tutorial covering the scenario you want to achieve, the tutorial is cookie-less and it depends only on bearer tokens which is the right way when you want to build SPA, you can check the series of posts here http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/